# Prove that the Goldbach conjecture implies that for each even integer $2n$ there exist integers $n_1$ and $n_2$ with $\sigma(n_1) + \sigma(n_2) = 2n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My try so far :

If goldbach conjecture is true, then every even number can be expressed as sum of two prime numbers :

$p_1 + p_2 = 2n$

How should I proceed further ?

Comment: If $p$ is prime, what is $\sigma(p)$? So you want two primes that add up to some even number other than $2n$...

Comment: $\sigma(p) = 1 + p$

Comment: And "My try so far:" ought to include, you know, what you've tried so far. :)

Comment: $\sigma(p_1) + \sigma(p_2) = 2 + p_1 + p_2$

Comment: but how this proves that any even number can be constructed from any two arbitrary prime combination ?

Comment: basically im running in circles on this proof, im not so sure of goldbach conjecture or the proof... seeing these for the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put it straight, write $2n-2$ as a sum of two primes (it is possible since $2n-2$ is even and you assumed that the Goldbach conjecture holds):
$$2n-2 = p_1 + p_2.$$
Then:
$$\sigma(p_1)+\sigma(p_2) = (p_1+1)+(p_2+1) = p_1+p_2+2 = 2n. $$

Comment: And a few small values of $ n $ must be treated separately.

Comment: Instead of showing $2n-2$ is a sum of two primes, is it possible to represent $2n$ as sum of two primes ?

Comment: If you assume the Goldbach's conjecture yes, since $2n$ is even.

Comment: I see it now thanks :)